# React Native ScrollY Interpolate error Tried to get frame out of range index NaN

Tags: react-native, animation, scrollview, nan

I am trying to animate a View to increase in height and overlap an image using the `Animate` tool from React-Native. The problem is that when I try this I keep getting an error 
`Tried to get frame out of range index NaN`

I used this code for a previous project of mine and it worked fine, however I'm not sure what the issue is now. Here is my code:

```
export default class InformationScreen extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      scrollY: new Animated.Value(0),
    }
  }
  render() {
        const headerHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
        outputRange: [HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT, HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT],
  });
    return (
<View>
    <Image style={{width:SCREEN_WIDTH, height:SCREEN_WIDTH}} resizeMode="cover" source={this.state.data.featured_image? {uri: this.state.data.featured_image} : require('../assets/noImage.jpg')}/>
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 1, width:SCREEN_WIDTH, height: SCREEN_HEIGHT/0.99, alignSelf:'center', position: 'absolute'}} scrollEventThrottle={16} onScroll={Animated.event([{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.state.scrollY}}}])}>
        <Animated.View style={{height:headerHeight}}>
//information goes here
        </Animated.View>
    </ScrollView>
 </View>
)}
}
```

Comment: it might have something to do with your styles for ScrollView, e.g. how come theres `flex: 1` and `height` and on top of that `position: absolute`? Try removing components one by one and see where it crashes, start with replacing Animated.View with ordinary View

Comment: good idea. When I removed `Animated` I got a long error regarding JSON value then it ends saying `of type NSMutableDictionary cannot be converted to a ABI36_0_0ygValue` do you know anything about that?

Comment: looks like you removed Animated.View, but not its animated height (`headerHeight`), remove that too